# VSCode: Как сдвинуть выделенный код в multi-line режиме?

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio-code

Всем привет! Банально не понимаю как сдвинуть выделенные строки кода на один пробел влево или вправо(имеется в виду не табуляция, а именно пробел).

Comment: Зажмите ALT и начните выделение вначале текста (не весь текст, а начало) и жмите что нужно дальше, хоть пробел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жмите на Ctrl+Shift+Alt и двигайте стрелки вниз\вверх. Далее таб или пробел сколько нужно раз. Все это достаточно просто узнается из настроек горячих клавиш в VSCode.

Рекомендую почитать документ [Visual Studio Code Tips and Tricks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks)

Answer (score 4):

Просто зажмите ALT при выделении, выделите начало нужных строк и начните вводить все, что вашей душе будет угодно.

Вот пример того, как это выглядит (правда в Notepad++, думаю VS Code этим не обделена):

[image: Result]

Comment: Можно спросить с помощью какой проги можно быстро гифки с рабочего стола сделать?)

Comment: @TEA Мне как то посоветовали LICEcap, так ей и пользуюсь)